# VB6 activating VB.Net without UAC

Tags: vb.net, vb6

We have a VB6 program (developed over many years) that gets installed by us on customers machines.
I have now added a VB.Net program to the mix that gets run (ShellExecute'ed)from the VB6 program under certain circumstances.
Is there any way that I can prevent customers machines (running W7/8/10) popping up the UAC dialog box?
The VB.Net prog has a Manifest that contains all the stuff that others have suggested and make no difference:

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    </requestedPrivileges>
    <applicationRequestMinimum>
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetreference="FullTrust"     permissionSetReference="FullTrust" />"
    <PermissionSet version="1" ID="FullTrust" unrestricted="true" SameSite="site" Unrestricted="true">
    <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.2.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
    </PermissionSet></applicationRequestMinimum>
```

Any help gratefully received
Cheers
Dave

Comment: Aside from turning off UAC on the client computer, which is probably not what you are looking for. If you had a way for a program to bypass UAC, that would render UAC completely useless. However, if you can identify what the .Net code is doing that requires admin level access, you might be able to change the .Net code and work around it. For example, I wrote a program that accessed some XML files which were stored in the Program Files directory, this requires admin access. I changed the location of the XML files to an App Data folder and admin access was no longer required.

Comment: I am not sure which is causing the UAC - Access by doing the shellexecute or .Net by doing something 'illegal'. I am accessing 3 files in the .net prog which I have moved to ProgramData and access them there (makes no difference) but I am also doing a lot of SQL reads.writes etc - could that be the cause?

Comment: Does the vb.net application pop the UAC when it runs directly (without vb6 wrapper)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved...
Changed the ShellExecute in the VB6 prog to a shell and problem solved